# Folding tags in emacs nxml-mode

Tags: xml, emacs, folding, nxml

The interwebs are full of ancient doctrines for folding code in the Glorious Emacs Editor. Among them are folding.el, outline-minor-mode, and fold-dwim.el. Alas, my poor unenlightened mind cannot write the necessary elisp configuration.

Please help a mortal fold tags in nxml-mode, preferably with TAB. If relevant, I use viper and vimpulse.

Answer (score 6):

Its called outlining in nxml-mode, its in section 5 of the nxml-mode documentation. Which begins ...

> 5 Outlining
>
> ---
>
> nXML mode allows you to display all or
> part of a buffer as an outline, in a
> similar way to Emacs' outline mode.
> An outline in nXML mode is based on
> recognizing two kinds of element:
> sections and headings. There is one
> heading for every section and one
> section for every heading.  A section
> contains its heading as or within its
> first child element.  A section also
> contains its subordinate sections (its
> subsections).  The text content of a
> section consists of anything in a
> section that is neither a subsection
> nor a heading.

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/nxml-mode.html#Outlining

Comment: None of the nxml commands work. Instead, the minibuffer displays "not in section"

Comment: @Natan, that's because your document, like most documents, doesn't have the structure needed for this to work (and even if it did, you'd have to configure the lists of section and heading elements).  I think this is a well-known limitation on the usefulness of nxml-mode outlining.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I'm upvoting your answer, but I'm going to wait for another solution that doesn't involve nxml-mode's outlining.

Answer (score 4):

There finally is an answer at
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/the-old-how-to-fold-xml-question, using `hideshow`.

If and when the emacs.stackexchange gets out of its beta stage, this question might become obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need to edit unspecified xml, I suggest using `web-mode` instead of `nxml-mode`. It supports node folding.

Emacs seems to open `.xml` files in `nxml-mode` by default. I guess `nxml-mode` is [useful for working with xml validated against a schema](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/nxml-mode/Introduction.html). However, if you just want to edit some un-specified xml with convenient tools, it seems that `web-mode` may be a better choice.

I found this question searching for a way to do the latter, so I thought I'd share.